# JavaScript Выполнение скрипта в теле страницы после загрузки

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такая задача, встроить `iframe` с документом в страницу. Сия красота загружается с третьего сайта и через JavaScript:

1. с сервиса асинхронно получаем такой тег

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/embeddedWidget?wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhCLlCGc-XhVQGnsG_NX5Xls1tBCDqCPE-Xz-zk8X_ooGxKzIxxyZ6oKL6iCqsAHLS8*"></script>
   ```
2. Вставляем его в `innerHTML` блока, где необходимо отобразить форму. Но он не работает.
3. Если выполнить в браузере ссылку напрямую то получаем:

   ```
   document.write('<iframe src="https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhCLlCGc-XhVQGnsG_NX5Xls1tBCDqCPE-Xz-zk8X_ooGxKzIxxyZ6oKL6iCqsAHLS8*&hosted=false&token=&firstName=&lastName=&nameEditable=true" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; min-width: 600px;"></iframe>');
   ```

Как же мне все это заставить работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставлять нужно куда-то, если вставлять в `body`, то вот так всё работает:

```js
var html = '<iframe src="https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhCLlCGc-XhVQGnsG_NX5Xls1tBCDqCPE-Xz-zk8X_ooGxKzIxxyZ6oKL6iCqsAHLS8*&hosted=false&token=&firstName=&lastName=&nameEditable=true" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; min-width: 600px;"></iframe>';

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Если конкретно в какой-то блок, то по `ID`, можно вот так:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Дело в том, что предполагалось вставлять изначально Script. Пришлось его переконвертировать в IFrame, потому что кидало ошибку: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.